# where to access the website administration tool in visual studio 2008 professional?

Tags: visual-studio

does anyone know where to access the website administration tool in visual studio 2008 professional?

Answer (score 11):

That depends on whether you are using Web sites or Web application projects.

For web sites it is *Website --> ASP.NET configuration*.

For Web application it is *Project --> ASP.NET configuration*.

Comment: If anyone is as lame as I am, I would just note that you have to have the web project selected in your solution for this option to appear.

Comment: on VS 2012 - its PROJECTS -> asp.net configuration

Answer (score 1):

Open a Web project and use the Project menu, ASP.NET Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Website -> ASP.NET Configuration